# Subtract Multiple Value from one Value row wise until it zero

Tags: sql

I have to maintain aging of Inventory where I have to show that quantity of one product is pending with Inventory department from how much days..

It will subtract on first come first basis...**I mean in case of Product P001 then 5500 will subtract 1000 first then rest quantity will subtract 2000 and so on until it will be zero..**

```
Department  |Product  | Date               | Quantity  |Indicator
------------+---------+--------------------+-----------+---------
D001        |P001     | 1Jul2017           | 1000      |ADD
D001        |P001     | 10Jul2017          | 2000      |ADD
D001        |P001     | 15Jul2017          | 3000      |ADD
D001        |P001     | 16Jul2017          | 2000      |ADD
D001        |P001     | 18Jul2017          | 5500      |SUBTRACT
D001        |P002     | 12Jul2017          | 3000      |ADD
D001        |P002     | 14Jul2017          | 2000      |ADD
D001        |P002     | 15Jul2017          | 4000      |SUBTRACT
```

And the final output should be something like. if today's date is 31Jul2017

```
Department  |Product  | Date               | Quantity  |AgeinginDays
------------+---------+--------------------+-----------+---------
D001        |P001     | 15Jul2017          | 500       |16
D001        |P001     | 16Jul2017          | 2000      |15
D001        |P002     | 14Jul2017          | 1000      |17
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Anyone??? Please help

Comment: . . I would suggest that you delete this question (it already has two close votes).  Then, ask another question.  Be sure to tag it with the correct database.   Explain what `AgeinginDays` is supposed to be and explain how the `date` column is determined.